# How to connect Wireless Keyboard when new hdd on imac 27

Tags: keyboard, wifi, imac, install, hdd

I have an iMac 27 emc 2390, i just had a hdd failure, so i bought a new hdd, plug it in and then start my imac with the instal dvd in.
The point is that my keyboard isn't recognize so i can't boot on the cd so i can t reinstal the OS.
Any ideas please?

i bought a USB keyboard, plug it in, but it seems to work only when the folder ? appears. the keyboard isn't responding before that, making it impossible to hold Option or C or anything else.

Comment: what keyboard model, you might need a USB since the BT service is not installed or active.

Comment: I just bought a usb keyboard, but it only start working when the Folder with question mark appears on screen.

Comment: I have my Instal dvd in, it's a new HDD, i can't boot on the DVD because none of my keyboard react a the start.

Comment: This is what i am saying, NO keyboards are reacting....so it just doesn t work. My wireless official apple keyboard isn t connected to the mac anymore ( new batteries etc.) so i bought a new usb keyboard, but it begin to work only when the folder? appears, not before, meaning the C button doesn t work on boot.

Comment: Turn off your Mac by pressing and holding its power button for a few seconds.
Press the power button once to turn your Mac back on. Then, hold down the Option key on your keyboard until the Startup Manager appears.

Comment: thank you, now i have the mouse on the screen but no logo, no where to click, nothing to do, grey screen with a mouse.?

Comment: I would suggest you redo the procedure :), we are making progress here.

Comment: well, still the same, the mouse in the middle of the screen.  On the usb keyboard i press and hold "alt gr" because no option button, is that ok ?

Comment: "alt" is the Option key on macs keyboards

Comment: well, still the same, only the cursor of the mouse and nothing else, and the dvd doesn't go out anymore. With the old HDD, the dvd went out automaticly after a while but not anymore with the new hdd.

Comment: Try different USB port, and tell me where does the mouse comes from ?

Comment: i tryed already, it is the same, the cursor just pop in the middle of the screen. Small black cursor.

Comment: Bad or incorrect USB keyboard, your system thinks it is a mouse ? is it the one with battery ? or just tell me the model.

Comment: ok, i pluged back my failing hdd, and try option on my usb keyboard, finally i got the Mac HD logo to click on but not the dvd logo...and finally my dvd went out of the rom. so i have my apple logo back and spinning wheel ( which will spin forever). Would it be possible that my HDD and My rom died at the same time

Comment: i dont know what happen but i suddenly got the apple hardware test running. still running.

Comment: this is the error it detected : 4MOT/4/40000003: HDD- 1391

Comment: You probably pressed D during start up :) that will start the AHT. The error could be the HDD it self or its build in fan. Try holding the C during start up (with DVD in)

Answer (score 1):

Since the OS is not installed on the new HDD the Bluetooth is not operational.

Get a USB keyboard.

Push and hold the power button for **5 seconds**!

Then release the power button and push and hold the option key to get the select the os to boot from (having the DVD with OS in the drive).

Alternatively press and hold the C key to boot from the DVD.

Comment: Holding C won't load the dvd, holding Option won't show me the dvd but the hdd ( the failing one). When the new one is in, it just shows me the mouse cursor with no HDD nor DVD to boot from eventho the dvd is in.

Comment: You got the Apple Hardware test to run. Can you repeat that or not, or did you use the wrong DVD disk.

Comment: ok, i can repeat with the hardware test holding D ( application dvd in) with the failing HDD. The holding C won t work with the instal dvd in and the failing hdd

Comment: I took off the failing hdd and replaced it with the new one, holding D with the Appli DVD in, Nothing, holding c with OSx Instal dvd in, nothing.Holding Option, still the cursor but no HDD no DVD to select. i try nvram/pram, this is ok, reboot auto. i try safe mode (shift) nothing, safe mode ( shift-command-v) nothing.

Comment: The instal DVD and application DVD are perfectly clean with no scratch at all. They keep going out of the rom after a while.

Comment: I tryed putting a Ubuntu 9.04 ver disk to the rom and it appears as a logo ( holding option)..so now i am installing Ubuntu.

Comment: are you telling me that your os disk was bad all along ?

Comment: It isnt bad as it isn t scratch at all, but i found on an other forum a guy who had the problem as me. His Dvd os wouldn t work as a boot disk, so he installed ubuntu and then use the OS disk to install mac os from ubuntu